# Atualizando o tamanho do fancybox dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Olá,

Eu preciso redimensionar o tamanho de uma fancy box dinamicamente a partir de um evento `onClick` que irá mostrar outros componentes na página.

Tentei utilizar o seguinte trecho de código [encontrado aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768852), e este redimensiona a página mas dá o seguinte erro, além de não centralizar o fancybox na página.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){b.open.apply(this,arguments)}
>   has no method 'center'

Além disso, utilizando este método, ao redimensionar o navegador, a Fancybox volta ao seu tamanho inicial.

Existe algum modo de contornar estes problemas? Estou utilizando a versão 2.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira:

```
$("#seuBotao").click(function () {
        parent.$fancybox.update();
});
```

Lembrando que para que isso funcione corretamente você precisa que na chamada do FancyBox o atributo **autosize** seja **true**

Exemplo:

```
$("#fancy").fancybox({
        width: 750,
        height: 550,
        autoSize: true
});
```